# How to avoid inserted entity to be selected after insert in EF Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-sql-database, entity-framework-core

I have a lot of inserts that are just for log purposes on an Azure DB, and I see that now most of the DTU usage is taken by this logging.

The load of the database is not because of the insert itself, but because after insert, but because the `CreationDate` field is being generated by the database and EFCore selects it after the insert.

In order to solve the "datetime2" error conversion, I have defined the `CreationDate` field as `entity.Property(e => e.CreationDate).HasColumnType("datetime").HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");`

So EF calls the DB after insert:

```
(@p0 uniqueidentifier)SELECT [CreationDate]
FROM [MyLogs]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [Id] = @p0
```

Is there a way to avoid this behavior, and just let the entity not tracked after insert?

For now the only way I see is to ignore the CreationDate field from the entity model as it is not used. `entity.Ignore(e => e.CreationDate);`

Comment: At present there is no easy way to do it. Filed https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/9118 on EF repo to track the feature

Comment: If entity framework isn't giving you the outcome/performance that you're looking for, to me this suggests it's a situation better suited for a sproc or custom `SqlCommand`.

Comment: @mathijspim it is a workaround, but not really nice one as it implies writing SQL code in .NET code

Comment: I disagree, I think the point of Entity Framework is to get the baseline going quickly. As soon as complexity grows beyond the standard CRUD operations, or if performance is a feature (which it is), then you need to go lower level. Anything can be abstracted.

Comment: It is a point of view I would not debate, because all options are possible depending on the specific case. However in my case I solved it, waiting for a nice solution by 1. Putting the request in an other thread, 2. Archiving the huge log table from time to time, 3. Getting rid of Azure for that kind of job

Comment: Fix for this is planned for EF Core 7.0: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/26797

Comment: Whoo, 5 years later, better late than never :D

Answer (score 1):

I propose you two solutions, one that relies on database and one that is entirely managed by EF core.

### Use a shadow property (default managed by db)

If you doesn't need to access the CreationDate in the EF entity (or at least you normally doesn't need this value), you could use [shadow property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties).

eg.

```
entity.Property<DateTime>("CreationDate")
            .HasDefaultValueSql("GETDATE()");
```

If you need this value you can get it using dbContext

```
context.Entry(item).Property("CreationDate").CurrentValue;
```

The value could also be used for searching or ordering items.

### Initialize value in .NET / EF (customizing the db context)

On the other side, if the CreationDate must be an effective property of the entity why you don't initialize it in .NET.

If you don't want to initialize on the constructor of your entities you could override `SaveChanges` method of the data context and set the value before save is performed:

```
public override int SaveChanges() {
  foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries()) {
    if (entry.State != EntityState.Added) continue;
    if (entry.Entity is ICreationDateEntity contextEntity)  {
       contextEntity.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
    }
  }
  return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

*Note*: you must also override, in the same way, `SaveChangesAsync`

I supposed to use an interface to intercept all entities that has a creation date.

I used this approach in the past to initialize fields like LastChangeUserId and LastChangeTimestamp.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to ignore the property. Create the default constructor and initialize the property from server side.

```
public  class User 
{
  public User()
    {
        this.CreationDate= Datetime.UTC.Now; 
    }
 public int UserId {get;set;}
 public Datetime CreationDate {get;set;}
}
```

It will be executed when you initialize the class.